# Css loader invalid option with Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, css-loader

I use next js in my app (it automatically uses webpack) , here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myreact",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.4",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "next": "^8.0.3",
    "next-images": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  }
}
```

And here is my next.config.js:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withCSS(withImages());
```

However, when I use npm run dev, it always throw an error:

```
ValidationError: CSS Loader Invalid Options

options should NOT have additional properties
Could not find files for /index in .next/build-manifest.json
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

I have tried to google but I found no solution to my problems.

Comment: I think you should provide your webpack config rather than package.json file

Comment: Next js automatically config webpack, so I don't need to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the new `css-loader` (v2.0.0), that added an options validation.

You can print the cssLoader options from the webpack config, and remove the redundant one.

For printing the webpack config, you need to change you `next.config.js` file to that:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withCSS(withImages({
  webpack: (config, options) => {
     console.log(config);
     return config;
  }
}));
```

Before that, you should not install your dep (next-css) dep (css-loader), try to remove it from you package.json and reinstall again, this should solve, if not, try what I've suggested.

There is a github thread regarding that: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/863#issuecomment-445747386.